# How do I get past the installation failure "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for Docker Desktop 3.3.3?

Tags: docker, installation, uninstallation

I have been trying to update the version of Docker Desktop on my laptop.  The latest version as of a couple of weeks ago is Docker Desktop 3.3.3.  I downloaded the installer and double clicked on it to begin the installation.  I confirmed execution, resulting in a window saying "Downloading package", with a heading of "Extracting installation manifest..."  Then a window saying "Do you want to replace your current version of Docker Desktop 3.3.1 (63152) with this new one (64133)?" appears.  After I click on "Yes", this attached error window pops up.  I tried stopping and uninstalling the previous version (3.3.1), but my PC refuses to do this.  I am at the end of my rope trying to get my PC to do the simplest installation.  I have been working with Docker for just over a month and want to do some tutorials and labs so that I can hit the ground running once I have real work to do with it.  I would appreciate any help I can get.
[image: Docker Desktop 3.3.3 Installation failed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem as you.
You have to delete the key "Docker Desktop" and all its sub-keys, situated at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" in the Windows Key Registry.

Comment: This approach is a bit unconventional.  It is similar to what occurs if there is a copy of SQL Server on a machine that must be reinstalled with the same version.   To install, there must be no previous copy in the folders and no previous registry entry.   What is missing here is that the key should be backed up before deletion.  Also, in the registry, there is an uninstallstring that can run without taking this somewhat extreme approach.